# Past perfect e.g. “had hoped”?

Tags: conjunctions, past-perfect, negation

> They **had hoped** to get to the summit, but Travers fell ill at base camp.

Is this sentence a negative sentence?

Does “had hoped” mean that “they” did not get there?

Comment: the conjunction *but* introduces something in contrast or unexpected; however, on the contrary.

Answer (score 3):

'HAD HOPED' here conveys the meaning that they planned and the conjuction

```
 but
```

introduces contradiction. so  the overall meaning is

```
 They did not go to summit.
```